# Windows store app - two elements one object binding

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-store-apps

What is the best way to acchieve this, what I am going to describe bellow.

I have two textboxes with twoway bindings on the same object and same property.
Now, when I update text in one textbox I wish other textbox to grab the same value again from object. Is that even possible, or I have to do this manually. For an example, I can use TextChanged event and set this value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can bind a single property to two controls

If this class is your `DataContext` (viewmodel)

```
public class Bind : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private string _text1;
   public string text1
   {
      get
      {
         return _text1;
      }
      set
      {
         _text1=value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("text1");
      }
   }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
  {
     if (PropertyChanged != null)
     {
         PropertyChanged(this, 
             new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
     }
  }  
}
```

In XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
 <UserControl.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:Class1/>
 </UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <TextBox Width="150" Height="50" Text="{Binding text1, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding text1, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0,232,0,0"/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Yea I know that. It was missunderstanding.
Well in your case...when you update value of first textbox, second textbox automatically update his. Without c#. if this is possible at all.